# CSS - Implement different fonts of a font-family

Tags: html, css, webfonts, google-font-api

I have the font-family Roboto with two different font-types (400 and 500i)

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500i" rel="stylesheet">
```

I would like to implement 500i, but this:

```
p {
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

just allows me to use the 400 font.

How can I implement the 500i without removing the 400?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specifying Style and Weight for Google Fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256065/specifying-style-and-weight-for-google-fonts)

Comment: @Adrian Mayr - Just an FYI there is a helpful [StackOverflow Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you can review to increase timely responses from the community. One major help to expediting a search on SO is to always select an answer to questions posed in your original post. If an answer is provided (below) you'll benefit by adding a comment to the answer explaining why that answer is failing, then the community is prompted to look deeper. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Define both `bold` and `italic` on the element:

```
    p {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 500;
        font-style: italic;
    }
```

---

**NOTE**
If you have the Roboto font installed locally you'll need to add `script=all rev=2` in the following manner:

```
p {
    font-family: 'Roboto script=all rev=2', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

If the font is installed locally the browser is going to rely on that font and ignore the web-font. This [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39405766/roboto-font-bolder-with-firefox) covers this. I can't say with any certainty but it seems likely that adding `script=all rev=2` by default is the way to go due to the fact we don't know if our sites visitors have a particular font installed. If you navigate to the [Roboto font offering](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto?selection.family=Roboto:400,500i) and inspect (using a browsers dev-tools) the 'Medium Italic' example we see the `font-family` property is using `script=all rev=2` by default.